# How to add a button from custom object to a page layout like Account?

Tags: custom-button, custom-object, page-layout

A button is created in the custom object, is there any way to add the button to the page layout of any layout such as Account/Opportunity?
I had to add the button to the custom object because the force ide was not including the custom buttons and links created in the account customizations, and so wasnt able to deploy them. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Buttons are tied to objects; you will have to add a new custom button for each object in which you want the button to appear.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with the approach.
1) As mentioned by Marina Martin, custom buttons and links are associated to the object for which they have been created and you can't add them to a different object.
2) You could have used change set to deploy the custom buttons and links along with the page layout to the required org. There was no need to create button on custom objects just for the sake of deployment

Comment: My requirement is to create a button that can be added to a page layout as per the convenience of the one installing the package. I am new to salesforce, but as far as i understand, each user can customize their page and thus imposing a particular page layout on them does not sound like a good idea. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Also, if my approach is wrong can you tell me how to create buttons that can be deployed through force IDE(package.xml).

Comment: Pagalayouts are tied to recordtypes + profiles and not individual users. So each profile can be assigned a different pagelayout but the same is not true for users.